# Zend translate strip line breaks

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm kind of new to the zend framework, so this migth be a stupied question :-)

But, How do I keep my line breaks using the Zend_Translate ?  and a csv-langauge file?
F.X: `"Home" => "Casa <br /> (Home)",`

but it show me result like this:

```
 Casa <br /> (Home)
```

i expected:

> Casa 
>  (Home)

Anyone know how to make line break in zend translate?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by myself. I found Zend not change any thing you put into translation but escape html from Zend form auto escape my html code. And i add this code into Zend_Form in __construct function like this:

```
foreach ($this->getElements() as $element){
            if(is_object($element->getDecorator('label'))){
                $element->getDecorator('label')->setOption('escape', false);
            }
        }
```

and it solved my problem